# ECS migration from EC2 to Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-fargate

I am trying to migrate from Amazon `ECS EC2` to `Fargate`. Here I have made some changes as per recommendation from https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/migrating-your-amazon-ecs-containers-to-aws-fargate/. I am using amazon cloudformation to create/update the resources.

```
ECSTaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
        Family : !Join ["_", [!Ref "AppName", !Ref "ComponentName", !Ref "TargetEnv" ]]
        NetworkMode: "awsvpc"
        ExecutionRoleArn: arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole
        TaskRoleArn: 
            Fn::Sub: 
                [ 
                    "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/exec_dp_${TargetEnv}",
                    { 
                        TargetEnv: !Ref "TargetEnv"
                    }
                ]
        RequiresCompatibilities:
          - "FARGATE"
        Memory: "512"
        Cpu: '256'
        ContainerDefinitions:
```

Here the problem is when I try to create the stack it gives me error as below:

> Unable to assume the service linked role. Please verify that the ECS service linked role exists

I have also tried creating service linked role something like below:

```
AwsEcsTaskExecutionRole:
     Type: AWS::IAM::Role
     Properties:
        Path: /
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
             Version: 2012-10-17
             Statement:
                     - Effect: Allow
             Principal:
             Service: ecs.amazonaws.com
             Action: sts:AssumeRole
        ManagedPolicyArns:
             - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/aws-service-role/AmazonECSServiceRolePolicy
```

and then specified it as
ExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt AwsEcsTaskExecutionRole.Arn

Its not working. Any direction regarding would really help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer:

Run this command: `aws iam create-service-linked-role --aws-service-name ecs.amazonaws.com`

Long answer:

AWS introduced [Service-Linked Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using-service-linked-roles.html). For old AWS accounts or if you never created an ECS cluster by hand in the console, you have to run the command above to have the role created.

Comment: is there any way to achieve this using cloudFormation?

Comment: I thought about using a CustomResource to create/delete the service-linked-role, however it's a unique role for the whole account (regardless of the region). This means that if you delete the stack that had created the role it would have a potential effect on other stacks in your account. In AWS, some things cannot be automated, such as support request for increasing a service limit. This is supposed to be fixed for new AWS account but in the meantime I suggest you just run the command and document what you did.

Comment: Thanks for your quick input. Here our guys wants to have complete control over the IAM. If you can update your answer with link to cloudFormation info on this, then that would be great thing.